# I want to animate to a certain frame when button is clicked - requestAnimationFrame

Tags: requestanimationframe

Hi I have an animation that is a sequence of 41 jpeg images. I created an overlay for button clicks and I wanted to basically click any of those buttons and have the animation always go to a certain frame. If you look at the sphere that is labeled "Patient Journey", that's where I want whichever sphere that is clicked to move into that position. 
    var animate;
    var fps          = 6,
    currentFrame = 0,
    totalFrames  = 42,
    img          = document.getElementById("myImage"),
    currentTime  = rightNow();

```
function rightNow() {
  if (window['performance'] && window['performance']['now']) {
  return window['performance']['now']();
  } else {
  return +(new Date());
  }
}


function animloop(time){
   var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;

   currentFrame += (delta * fps);

   var frameNum = Math.floor(currentFrame);

if (frameNum >= totalFrames) {
    currentFrame = frameNum = 0;
    }

animate = requestAnimationFrame(animloop);

img.src = "images/sequence/CommercialExcellence_09_12_15_000" +
(frameNum < 43 ? "" : "0") + frameNum + ".jpg";

currentTime = time;

}(currentTime);
```

[image: 3D Spheres that rotate around the person]

Answer (score 0):

Is your animation moving the spheres along the red path until the clicked sphere is in front of the woman?

If yes, then instead of loading 42 full images, you might try this resource friendly trick:

- a containing div with position:relative.
- 1 background (==everything but the spheres) with z-index=1.
- 6 sphere images with z-index=2 with position:absolute.
- woman's head image with z-index=3 (this visually 'hides' any sphere that's behind the woman).

Then in the animation frame,

- Calculate the appropriate position for each sphere,
- Use CSS `top` and `left` to move each sphere to the calculated position.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. I will let you know how it works. Thanks for your time.